# replace space before/after certain characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's conventional to have spaces before punctuation symbols in French.

I've got texts like this:

> Paul m'a dit « Bonjour ! »

I'd like a jquery/javascript function to replace regular spaces with non-breaking spaces before the following characters:

```
! : ? … ; »
```

and after this character:

```
«
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Like this (**EDIT:** Tested, works)

```
function replaceNonBreaking(text) {
    return text.replace(/ (!|:|\?|…|;|»)/g, "&nbsp;$1").replace('« ', '«&nbsp;');
}
```

Replacing all occurrences of "[space][special-char]" to "[non-breaking space][that special-char]" in the string.

Comment: In this case with french big punctuation, the recommanded non-breaking space code is `&#8239;` which is narrower than `&nbsp;` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Width_variation).

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a far better regex way than this one (regex is my downfall), but this one works:

```
str = str.replace(/\s([!:\?…;»])/g, function (el1, el2) {
    return '&nbsp;' + el2;
}).replace(/(«)\s/g, function (el1, el2) {
    return el2 + '&nbsp;';
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e0bq13tx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
var str = 'Paul m\'a dit : « Bonjour ! »';
var corrected_str = str.replace(/ (!|\:|\?|…|;|»)/g, '&nbsp;$1', str).replace('« ', '«&nbsp');
```

(I think you should add a non-breaking space before « too.)

Answer (score 0):

My Typescript helper function with the narrow no-break space code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Width_variation):

```
export function replaceNonBreaking(text: string): string {
  if (!text) { return text; }
  return text.replace(/ (!|:|\?|…|;|»)/g, '&#8239;$1').replace('« ', '«&#8239;');
}
```